# Unable to upload image despite successful submission via HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a custom PHP website hosted on a Plesk(Windows Hosting Server of Godaddy)

When I submit the form, all of the values get updated, but the image does not get updated. This is the error shown on the page

```
PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(../../../uploads/channels/3.jpg): failed to open stream: 
Permission denied in G:\PleskVhosts\dramatainment.com\httpdocs\dashboard\admin\actions\update_queries.php on line 50
PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php5E2E.tmp' to '../../../uploads/channels/3.jpg' in G:\PleskVhosts\dramatainment.com\httpdocs\dashboard\admin\actions\update_queries.php on line 50
```

I am using the code that I got from w3schools.com here is the link to that script
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems like you are trying to write to a location, you arent allowed to write to, as the current user.

Comment: yes you have to give 755 permision to your file upload folder

Comment: How do i do that? Can you please tell me

Comment: This is the error I get when I click on the change permissions link  
Internal error: filemng failed: Unable to get the object (G:\PleskVhosts\dramatainment.com\uploads) security info: (2) The system cannot find the file specified. at execute "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\admin\bin\filemng.exe" UmerAtiq --permissions --list-common "--file=G:\PleskVhosts\dramatainment.com\uploads" "--accounts=tmpCF93.tmp"(RunTime::RunAsUser::run line 221) (Error code 1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give write permission for destination folder to which you are moving image file.

Comment: if you are using linux based server then this should be like this: 

sudo chmod 755 directory_name

But in my opinion, better consult server admin.

Comment: I am using godaddy windows hosting. Now i know how do i change it. But here is the error i get when i click on the link to change permissions

Comment: This is the error I get when I click on the change permissions link  
Internal error: filemng failed: Unable to get the object (G:\PleskVhosts\dramatainment.com\uploads) security info: (2) The system cannot find the file specified. at execute "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\admin\bin\filemng.exe" UmerAtiq --permissions --list-common "--file=G:\PleskVhosts\dramatainment.com\uploads" "--accounts=tmpCF93.tmp"(RunTime::RunAsUser::run line 221) (Error code 1)